# Google Web Toolkit (GWT) rpc to Python server on Google App Engine (GAE)

Tags: json, eclipse, google-app-engine, gwt, pydev

I am building a web-based carbon foot-printing tool.

I have a mature Google Web Toolkit (GWT) client.

I have a mature Google App Engine (GAE) server in Python.
I'm using Eclipse plugins: PyDev, GWT, GAE

I want to exchange several of my classes containing several levels of nested data including Python numpy arrays (matrices).  (Sadly Jython does not support Numpy so I cannot use Jython.)

I can do this using Python Json on the server with GWT Type Overlays on the client but it feels a bit clunky.  I miss the automatic (de)serialization of GWT RPC.

I have looked at several GWT rpc options but (understandably) they  seem to use Java on the server and/or development seems to have stalled :

1. Hermes:
2. lovely.gwt.jsonrpc: similar to Hermes
3. RestyGWT: No Python end
4. python-gwt-rpc: old and in alpha
5. GWT AutoBean: looks promising for the client side but I'm unclear how to use in Python
6. gwt-rpc-plus: stalled 2010

Google shows:
No results found for +gwt +rpc +python

I'd welcome ideas and/or pointers

Thanks

Julian

Comment: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/protorpc/

Answer (score 0):

GWT-RPC only works with Java backend I believe. See [documentation](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication#DevGuideRemoteProcedureCalls)

> GWT provides an RPC mechanism based on Java Servlets to provide access to server side resources

Now, you can code your client in GWT and talk with your Python server using Remote Procedure Calls principle. Nothing prevents you to do this.

One way to do this is to write a REST API in your python backend. Then you can use RestyGWT in your client

RestyGWT is a GWT generator for REST services. You can target any backend with a REST api (written in Java, python or whatever ...)

Comment: Thanks Ronan,I've reconciled myself to using GWT Type Overlays by simplifying my nested classes.  Works reasonably well.  Best wishes Julian.